How to find type of a Python variable when hovering the mouse cursor over a variable in Visual Studio Code?
I want to find out its type when hovering over a variable with the mouse, but this does not work. Does anyone know how to do this? For example, when hovering over x, it writes some kind of Literal, although I directly declared the type of the variable as int.


For most cases, it will say the type (try x=1235.0 and you will see float), what you see here is that it's stored as a literal. From that, you should be able to tell its original type from what is contained in the brackets. I recommend understanding literals however, because if you would for example write x = [123] you would get list of int, not list of literal https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/literals-in-python/

Does not work. in this way, he determines only the type of float, but he cannot determine string or int

I know, but you yourself can realize what was the origin, if you see "..." then it was a string, if you see an integer it was an int, etc.

In the tooltip, Literal refers to typing.Literal, which is a special form used to define a type that is the set of all given literal values.
Easy to see that Literal[1] is a subtype of int, Literal['foo'] is a subtype of str and so on.
In this case, the type checker (Pyright) is able to infer a more specific type for x, so it went ahead and did just that. This is a feature, not a bug. Depending on the flow, this type might change:
(playground)
x = 1235
reveal_type(x)      # Literal[1235]

for _ in range(0):
    x += 2
    reveal_type(x)  # int

reveal_type(x)      # int

It should also be noted that this might or might not be the case with other type checkers; that is, this is implementation-specific. Take Mypy for example:
(playgrounds: Mypy, Pyright)
x1: int
x1 = 1235
reveal_type(x1)  # pyright => Literal[1235]
                 # mypy    => int

x2: int = 1235
reveal_type(x2)  # pyright => Literal[1235]
                 # mypy    => int

x3 = 1235
reveal_type(x3)  # pyright => Literal[1235]
                 # mypy    => int

x4 = 1233 + 2
reveal_type(x4)  # pyright => Literal[1235]
                 # mypy    => int

As far as I know, there is currently no setting to control this behaviour.
